# How do I append tags to photos with existing tags in Lightroom 3?

Tags: lightroom, software, metadata, tagging

Say my photos already have tags. I want to add one more tag to them, so I select them in Library, and in the Keyword pane I see those existing tags with asterisks (which means only some of the pics have this tag). Then I add new tag next to that one and press enter. As a result I see that the tags for individual photos changed to the one with literally asterisk. What is the proper way to append tags to multiple photos, already containing different tags?

Comment: -1 as the problem described is incorrectly observed and doesn't occur. The question is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observation in your question is incorrect: Lightroom never changes the tags to literally contain the asterisk. You can show this with a simple test:

- In the Grid module, choose a folder with more than one photo in it
- Tag the first photo **test1**
- Now select it and the second photo (using Ctrl/Cmd click to multi-select): the Keyword Tags pane inside the Keywording panel will correctly show **test1***
- Typing directly in that pane, change it to **test1*, test2** and hit Enter
- Now examine each photo in turn: the first has the tags **test1, test2** and the seconds just has **test2**.

You can also use the "Click here to add keywords" box (in the Keywording panel) or the Painter feature to achieve the same thing. Whichever way you do it, Lightroom will never alter a keyword to (e.g.) **test1***.

Comment: OK the problem was due to using space as delimiter instead of comma

Answer (score 1):

You may do it in 2 ways:

- Select multiple photos in Library **while being in grid view** and tag them in Keywording panel
- You can paint Keywords over photos with Painting feature - its cool but I find it a bit slow